# Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage'

Tags: swift

This is my code please help, I'm following a tutorial but i can't figure out whats wrong. please help.

i'm trying to make if the image selected, then perform segue to another view controller and display the image which had been selected before

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showImage"
    {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        vc.image = self.url[indexPath.row] //Error Cannot Assign a value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage'
    }
}
```

I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 2):

`vc.image = self.url[indexPath.row]` , you are having indexPath.row as string , you have to get the image from the string , inside your `self.url["here"]` use something like `UIImage(named:"imagename")`  , in all `self.url[UIImage(named:indexPath.row)` 
 and the view controller vc should have the image variable of type UIImage.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code working fine In Swift4,

```
    let subCategory = tableData[indexPath.row]
    let urlString = "https://cdn.urldecoder.org/assets/images/url_fb.png"
    print(urlString)
    let url = URL(string: urlString!)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    if let imageData = data {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        cell?.userPicImage.image = image
    }else {
        cell?.userPicImage.image = UIImage(named: "SomeEmptyImage")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**self.url[indexPath.row]** gives out a String value you can't directly assign string to image that's why it throws an error **Cannot Assign a value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage'**

So,You have to convert it to data as shown below.For instance

```
let ImageView = UIImageView()
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Small-Talk-image.jpg")!)
ImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

In your case the below code may help,I think **Self.url** is an array containing image URL's as string

```
if segue.identifier == "showImage"
{
    let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    let URLStr = self.url[indexPath.row] as! String
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: URLStr)!)
    vc.image.image = UIImage(data: data!) //Now it will work if vc.image is an UIImageView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple like this

```
let url = NSURL(string:"<image url>")
    let imagedata = NSData.init(contentsOf: url! as URL)

if imagedata != nil {
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data:imagedata! as Data)
}
```